# How can we execute a query in Julia with column names inside a list?

Tags: mysql, julia

I want to execute a query like:

`SELECT SID,SNAME,MARKS FROM TABLE;`

But this should be achieved in Julia with the column names inside a list:

`columns = ["SID","SNAME","MARKS"]`

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

```
fieldnames = ["col1","col2"]

query = "select "*join(fieldnames,",")*" from table;"
```